# Bluetooth detects no devices and vice versa in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: drivers, bluetooth

I am unable to find any device in Bluetooth and my system is not detected by any device while Bluetooth is on. Is there any driver I need to install for Bluetooth?

Edited:
It detects my bluetooth headphone but failed to pair up and it is not detecting any other bluetooth device.

output for `lsusb; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'`

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:b721 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04f2:b52b Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Post results from terminal for `lsusb; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'`

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you want to achieve and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: I have added the output of lsusb; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'  @Jeremy31

Answer (score 0):

When opening system settings and clicking on the Bluetooth option, I got the message 'No Bluetooth found'

This what worked for me to fix it (terminal command line):

```
sudo modprobe -r btusb
sudo modprobe btusb
sudo service bluetooth restart

sudo apt-get install blueman
```

Then go to Search for files on the computer (), type in `blueman` (this is the bluetooth manager).
You can then enable bluetooth once it opens up.

Comment: I install blueman but this doesn`t work .  Still it is not detecting any device

Comment: Once you install blueman, the System Settings for Bluetooth worked. So, when you type in 'blue' in the Search for files field, you will see two bluetooth icons: the manager and the ones from the system.  

1. Open Manager and 'Enable Bluetooth'

2. Open the other icon, from the system settings, and turn on bluetooth; also turn on visibilty. They are two separate sliders to move, on the same screen.

Comment: Blueman is a way of managing bluetooth, its unlikely to help set-up the right drivers and firmware that are probably needed in most cases to fix the issue, though with some (often older) OSs it does provide a better interface that may work better

Comment: I tried it. My system bluetooth is detecting a bluetooth headphone but is unable to pair for unknown reason. And it is not detecting any other bluetooth device like smartphone etc. May be i need some driver but i don`t know which one.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of TLP and it worked for me!!,

as mentioned in this forum https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=233527

you need to,

Get the ID of the bluetooth device by running `lsusb` (in my case it is Realtek, so the ID is 0bda:b721).

output of `lsusb`,

```
dinuka@dinuka-lap:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:b721 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f2:b52b Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04f3:0235 Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Now, change the line `#USB_BLACKLIST="1111:2222 3333:4444"` to `USB_BLACKLIST="<ID>"` (in my case to `USB_BLACKLIST="0bda:b721"`) in `/etc/default/tlp`.

Reboot and everything should work.